# Build error in Xcode on cloud-hosted Mac on VSTS

Tags: swift, xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm getting following error while building my project on cloud

> no such module 'RxCocoa' import RxCocoa
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileSwift normal arm64
> CompileSwiftSources normal arm64com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (2 failures) Error:
> **/usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65**

the reason is same as building on local machine when frameworks are not added in 'Link Binary With Libraries' then Xcode throw this error.

So my question is how to fix this issue in Xcode on cloud-hosted Mac?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you're using Cocoapods, make sure that `pod install` script is executed and `.xcworkspace` file is being compiled.

Comment: yes Cocoapods is there and `pod install` runs successfully and also I'm sure that `**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace` is selected

Comment: not `**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace`. It should be `/project.xcworkspace`

Comment: after replacing what you have suggested now I'm getting `##[error]Error: The Xcode workspace was specified, but it does not exist or is not a directory: /project.xcworkspace`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ok so just replacing `**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace` with `projectname.xcworkspace` fixed my issue

May be it will help others.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @MadLeo can you please share your yml file ? I’m having the same issue and changing to projectname.xcworkspace don’t work

Comment: no need to put yml, VSTS take care about this things and i have documented everything what i have done with VSTS here https://medium.com/@mkmk971/how-to-setup-ci-cd-for-ios-projects-with-jenkins-and-vsts-52ff730f20ea

Answer (score 2):

I have faced another issue and fixed this issue after 4 days.

Please check your 
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    scheme: '$(scheme)'

Most of example tell you "configuration" as "Release" if you have custom configuration please use particular name.