# Azure Pipeline 'No such module' despite using workspace

Tags: ios, module, cocoapods, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild

Trying to build Xcode project (with cocoa pods) in Azure-Pipeline, but getting `no such module` despite selecting the workspace.

Tried building locally with commands, worked successful. Tried setting different variables in the yml, didn't help.

Using this command works locally but fails in azure

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -workspace iosApp/iosApp.xcworkspace -scheme iosApp clean build
```

YML looks like this

```
  - script: /usr/local/bin/pod deintegrate
    workingDirectory: 'iosApp'
    displayName: 'pod deintegrate'

  - script: /usr/local/bin/pod install
    workingDirectory: 'iosApp'
    displayName: 'pod install'

  - task: Xcode@5
    inputs:
      actions: 'clean build'
      scheme: 'iosApp'
      sdk: 'iphonesimulator'
      configuration: 'Debug'
      workingDirectory: 'iosApp'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'iosApp/iosApp.xcworkspace'
      xcodeVersion: 'default'
      displayName: 'Building For iOS'
```

EDIT:

Still not working, however I realized that the module in question has a path associated with it, meaning it's local. 
i.e.
`pod 'Alamofire', :path => '~/Documents/Alamofire'`

This could be part of the issue, since the other pods included seem to be working.

Comment: Hi there, have the same problem. Any update on this? Appreciate

Answer (score 4):

This issue seemed be caused by the `xcode` task does not work on the correct workspace path.

You can try with updating the value of `xcWorkspacePath` to `ProjectName.xcworkspace`. Like the sample showed which modified from your scripts below:

```
- task: Xcode@5
    inputs:
      actions: 'clean build'
      scheme: 'iosApp'
      sdk: 'iphonesimulator'
      configuration: 'Debug'
      workingDirectory: 'iosApp'
      xcWorkspacePath: 'ProjectName.xcworkspace'
      xcodeVersion: 'default'
      displayName: 'Building For iOS'
```

Here has another reference: [Build error in Xcode on cloud-hosted Mac on VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677674/build-error-in-xcode-on-cloud-hosted-mac-on-vsts)

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue, because I have tried that in Azure and I get a different error of `The Xcode workspace was specified, but it does not exist or is not a directory`. I think the issue might be with the fact that the module in question  is local and has a local path associated.

Comment: Does the `pod install` script was executed and the `.xcworkspace`  file is being compiled?

Comment: I have the script task to `pod install`, which runs successfully according to the pipeline.